# PSTricks: problem with y-coordinate

Tags: pstricks

I have a problem with pstricks. I am not able to control the cartesian coordinate for the y-axis. I don't understand why. For example, I am drawing a line going from (x=1,y=4) to (x=6,y=4). I can control the x-coordinate, but not the y. Anyone can explain me where I am wrong?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
%\usepackage{pst-math}
\begin{document}

\psgrid
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm, fillstyle=solid}

\psline[linewidth=.05cm,arrowsize=0.25]{->}(1,4)(6,4)

\end{document}
```

And here what I get:

[image: Line is not at y=4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct behaviour. You didn't reserve any space for the
image, the reason why all macros place its contents into a box
of zero width and height. You have an empty line between `\psset`
and `\psline`. For TeX it is the same as `\par`, which starts a
new line and your current reference point (coordinate system) is 
moved down. Compare it with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\psgrid
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm, fillstyle=solid}%
%   
\psline[linewidth=.05cm,arrowsize=0.25]{->}(1,4)(6,4)

\end{document}
```

However, you are looking for something like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](7,5)
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm, fillstyle=solid}%

\psline[linewidth=.05cm,arrowsize=0.25]{->}(1,4)(6,4)
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

The environment `pspicture` reserves a box of width 7 and height 5.
Empty lines are now not valid.